# NetworkManager stop working in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: networkmanager, ubuntu-20.04

**Settings - Network:**

> Oops something has gone wrong. Please contact your software vendor.
> NetworkManager needs to be running.

```
~$ NetworkManager
NetworkManager: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: undefined symbol: gnutls_srp_allocate_client_credentials, version GNUTLS_3_4
```

**sudo service network-manager restart**

```
~$ sudo service network-manager restart
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**systemctl status NetworkManager.service**

```
~$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-06-18 16:49:27 MSK; 21min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
    Process: 5827 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 5827 (code=exited, status=127)

Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
```

**journalctl -xe**

```
~$ journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit NetworkManager.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jun 18 17:19:43 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6353 and the job result is done.
Jun 18 17:19:43 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 18 17:19:43 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 18 17:19:43 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6353 and the job result is failed.
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys sudo[8191]:   galls : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/galls ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service network-manager restart
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys sudo[8191]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6440 and the job result is failed.
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys sudo[8191]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 18 17:19:54 galls-Sys /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2576]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-0ms), your system >
Jun 18 17:19:54 galls-Sys /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2576]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-13ms), your >
Jun 18 17:19:59 galls-Sys /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2576]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-12ms), your >
Jun 18 17:20:11 galls-Sys /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2576]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-11ms), your >
lines 3103-3151/3151 (END)
```

**ifconfig**

```
~$ ifconfig
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension
```

Possible to fix it without network connection?

Comment: Exactly what sort of computer is this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ubuntu 20.04 or what you mean?

Comment: I meant the hardware.